# I cannot remove roles of user by using rolemanager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I trying to remove or add role for user by checkbox at UI but I got some error

```
await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName)
```

This code always return false and I cant check it.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

I still can get `roles` of `user`.
Can anyone explain the reason why I am getting this error?

```
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
private readonly RoleManager<Role> _roleManager;
private readonly IConfiguration _config;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

public UserService(UserManager<User> userManager, 
    SignInManager<User> signInManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager,
    IConfiguration config,
    IMapper mapper)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
    _config = config;
    _mapper = mapper;
}    
public async Task<ApiResult<bool>> RoleAssign(int id, RoleAssignRequest request)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    var listRole = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("admin");
    if (user == null)
    {
        return new ApiErrorResult<bool>("Tài khoản không tồn tại");
    }
    var removedRoles = request.Roles.Where(x => x.Selected == false).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var roleName in removedRoles)
    {
        if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName) == true)
        {
            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName);
        }
    }
    await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
    
    var addedRoles = request.Roles.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var roleName in addedRoles)
    {
        if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName) == false)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
        }
    }
    
    return new ApiSuccessResult<bool>();
}
```

Comment: did you check await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName); result ?

Comment: yes, i checked already and it returned a IdentityResult : "UserNotInRole"

Answer (score 0):

AS you are trying to remove role of user: you can do it in this way i hope it will work.
its just a basic example.
remove role code:

```
 ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(UserId.ToString());
            if (user != null)
            {
                foreach (var r  in user.Roles.ToList())
                {
                    user.Roles.Remove(r);
                }
            }
```

add role code::

```
  IdentityUserRole userrole = new IdentityUserRole();
                           //add user information in userrole according to your buisness logic
                            user.Roles.Add(userrole);
```

Comment: in the `user` don't have field Roles, what i have to do @hemant

Comment: UserManager.GetRoles(userId.ToString()); try this..

Comment: yes i can get list role by user but i can't use user.Roles.ToList(); i don't know the reason why

Comment: user roles belongs to IdentityUser class please check  public virtual ICollection<TRole> Roles { get; } this property exist or not.. as well check your ApplicationUser class inheriting  IdentityUser class..

Comment: my applicationUser has been inherited IdentityUser class and i said i can get roles by this code `var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);`

Comment: but when i delete role from the user it notification that UserNotInRole

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code about [UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser, String)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b795ac3546eb3e2f47a01a64feb3020794ca33bb/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1278)  method, you can find that it will return UserNotInRoleError if the user is not in the specificed role.

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var userRoleStore = GetUserRoleStore();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }

    var normalizedRole = NormalizeName(role);
    if (!await userRoleStore.IsInRoleAsync(user, normalizedRole, CancellationToken))
    {
        return UserNotInRoleError(role);
    }
    await userRoleStore.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, normalizedRole, CancellationToken);
    return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
}
```

To add/remove role for the specified user, you can try to check if role is existing and check if the user is already in role before you do adding/removing operation, like below.

*Add the specified user to the named role*

```
//add user to the named role

bool role_is_existing = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);

//if the specified role name is not existing
//create the the specified role
if (!role_is_existing)
{
    var role = new IdentityRole();
    role.Name = roleName;
    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
}

//check if the current user is a member of the given named role
var isInRole = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName);

if (!isInRole)
{
    //add to role
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
}
```

*Remove the specified user from the named role*

```
//check if the current user is a memeber of the given named role
var isInRole = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName);

if (isInRole)
{
    await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName);
}
```

> when i delete role from the user it notification that UserNotInRole

Please make sure the actual data in `AspNetRoles` table and check if the record for mapping current user and the specified role is stored in `AspNetUserRoles` table.

Comment: I did the same as you said, but I can only add and not delete. I also checked the records in the UserRoles table which were mapped between the Roles and Users table by their ids

Comment: my post has variables with the following values ​​`var user = a user` with fields, `var roles = "admin"`, `var listRoles = true`

Comment: Hi @tunggggg, please check if you stored `NormalizedName` for that role in `AspNetRoles` table.

Comment: Hi @tunggggg, any updates? Have you checked the `NormalizedName` of the record of the role?

Comment: Thanks, @Fei Han my problem solved, previously I used all 5.0, I downgraded SDK and ef to .netcore3.1 and ef 3.1.1 it worked, I don't know why but the code is still the same.